# Sharepoint Online - distribute custom web template

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365

I need to create a web template for **Sharepoint Online / Office 365** and distribute it as a WSP file.

I also have a local **SharePoint Server 2010 for development on my machine**. I created some webparts, they work on **SPS2010** and SharePoint Online, but now I want to create the webtemplate, because I need to create custom **teamsites** on demand.

What I got so far is the following:

- It appears that I **can't create** templates from SPS2010 for SPO, there are certain features not available on **SPO** and I can't remove these features from the `Onet.xml` without breaking the file and the resulting page (HTTP 404). Is there any way?
- For some reason I cannot create web templates from a website I created on a SharePoint Online instance, which I have access to. I get an error `Error exporting the list named "Master Page Gallery" at the URL: _catalogs/masterpage"` message and the build fails.

But, apart from that, is it possible to create a web template and then distribute as a WSP so other people can use it on other instances of SPO? It appears that there would be issues, because the FeatureIDs of installed features would not match or are they equal on any instance in SPO?

Thank you very much for your effort.

bash.d